# How to print the full line to the file if the string match with 5th field of the tab delimiter file in batch command

Tags: batch-file, window

Need to check the string inside the TAB delimiter file,if the 5th field of the line matched with the search string, then print the full line into another file.

Tab Delimiter File (in.txt):

```
123 phlips  usa 34  asdf    123
223 ryan    usa 33  555     123
324 alex    usa 43  asdf    555
235 bob     usa 22  555     123
555 ken     usa 43  asdf    123
```

Search String=`555`

Expected Output File (out.txt):

```
223 ryan    usa 33  555 123
235 bob     usa 22  555 123
```

Used below command but out put came the first field match lines,could you please help me where i amend the command for 5th field search only in TAB delimiter file.

```
findstr /b "\<555\>" in.txt >out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

expand your search pattern a bit:

```
findstr /BRC:".*    .*  .*  .*  555 .*" in.txt >out.txt
```

(sadly, Stackoverflow converts TABs to Spaces. There is no space in the pattern, only TABs)

`.` = "any character, `*` = "zero or more"

Another approach: Get and compare the 25th column explicitely:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "line="
for /l %%a in (1,1,50) do set "line=!line!%%a   "
echo %line%>t.txt
set "line="
for /l %%a in (2,1,51) do set "line=!line!%%a   "
echo %line%>>t.txt
set "line="
for /l %%a in (3,1,52) do set "line=!line!%%a   "
echo %line%>>t.txt
set "line="
for /l %%a in (4,1,53) do set "line=!line!%%a   "
echo %line%>>t.txt
set "line="
for /l %%a in (5,1,54) do set "line=!line!%%a   "
echo %line%>>t.txt
set "line="
for /l %%a in (0,1,49) do set "line=!line!%%a   "
echo %line%>>t.txt
endlocal

REM above block is just to generate a testfile    

for /f "delims=" %%a in (t.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=25" %%b in ("%%a") do (
    echo DebugLine. Column 25 is: "%%b"
    if "%%b"=="25" echo %%a
  )
)
```

(again, it's a TAB in `set "line=!line!%%a  "`, no spaces.)

**Notes:**
Slower than just `findstr`
Max "token" is 31. (`for` limitation)  *)
If any field is empty, this fails. (miscalculation, consecutive delimiters are treated as one)  *)
Has problems with some special chars.  *)

*) (can be corrected using more code, but will make it even slower)

Comment: @stephan.Thanks for your help.some clarifications that if i used only "." followed by TAB i got the line only 5th place where "555" present,but when used ".*"  got all lines where anywhere field "555" present.so i confused with(. = "any character,).if i want to match with 25th no fileds shall use "." with TAB upto 25 no field.

Comment: not sure, I understand. A dot in the pattern doesn not represent a dot, but "any character" (like a wildcard). To use a literal dot, you'd have to use `\.`. Also, there is a limit, how long the pattern can be. So it might have problems with the "25th filed"

Comment: added `/b` to findstr (inspired by Magoo's answer). Didn't matter with your example, but makes a difference if there are a lot of columns.

Comment: Your FINDSTR solution only works because the test data only has 6 columns, without a tab after the 6th column. The `.` matches a tab character. If the data has 10 columns, then your code matches all rows with `555` in any of columns 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9. You should use `[^tab]*` instead of `.*` (obviously tab represents the character).

Comment: I don't understand why you are looking in column 25 in your FOR /F code.

Comment: @dbenham: because sasmi stated in the first comment: `if i want to match with 25th` (when I interpret it corrrectly)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the comment

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "tab=   "
SET "nottab=[^%tab%]"
SET "nottabsequence=%nottab%*"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q47151351.txt"

FINDSTR /b /r /c:"%nottabsequence%%tab%%nottabsequence%%tab%%nottabsequence%%tab%%nottabsequence%%tab%555%tab%" "%filename1%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q47151351.txt` containing your data for my testing.

the variable `nottab` is set up to the regex that `findstr` uses to specify `any character except tab`. `Nottabsequence` to a sequence of such characters - just to make it easier to see what's going on. The `/b` on `findstr` means `matching at the beginning of the line`.